# Why is Swift Dictionary not bridgeable?

Tags: swift, dictionary, bridge, toll-free-bridging

Dictionary is a bridged type, why is it that I can switch from Swift dictionary to NSDictionary but not the other way around? (Compile Error: NSDictionary is not convertible to 'Dictionary')

According to Apple's doc:

All NSDictionary objects can be bridged to Swift dictionaries, so the Swift compiler replaces the NSDictionary class with [NSObject: AnyObject] when it imports Objective-C APIs.

```
import Foundation

var swiftDict = ["0": "zero"]

let nsDict:NSDictionary = swiftDict
let backToSwiftDict:Dictionary = nsDict
```

Answer (score 2):

This is correct but you have to perform a type safe cast from NSDictionary to a Dictionary

```
var swiftDict = ["0": "zero"]

let nsDict: NSDictionary = swiftDict
let backToSwiftDict: Dictionary = nsDict as Dictionary
```

Comment: Why is the cast necessary going from NS- to Swift? Can't compiler infer it's a bridged type?

Comment: No, you are then declaring a Swift Dictionary and try to assign an NSDictionary to it. The cast tells the compiler that you are sure about what you're doing. The reason it works from swift dict to NSDict is because an NSDict doesn't care about the type of it's fields. But a Swift dict does care and so it's not safe to simply let it be converted.

Comment: Don't totally get it - are you saying there are things in NSDictionary that can't be bridged back to Swift automatically? NSDict does care about the type of its field - everything stored in NSDict has to be NSObject-derived.

Answer (score 1):

... or you can cast it back into a dictionary with type-safe fields ...

```
var swiftDict = ["0": "zero"]
let nsDict:NSDictionary = swiftDict
let backToSwiftDict = nsDict as! [String:String]
```

Comment: Thanks - why as! instead of as?

Comment: `as!` is used to enforce a cast. it's used where you are sure that the cast will succeed. `as?` is used in situations where the cast might fail, typically in combination with optional binding, e.g. `let d = nsDict as? [String:String] {}` assigns the resulting dictionary to `d` only if the cast succeeds.